# End plot at last data point in pyplot time series

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pyplot chart that looks a bit like this:

[image: The chart in question]

How do I get the red and blue lines to stop at their last data point (May 13th and May 19th, respectively) instead of continuing a horizontal line to the far right?

Each line is composed of points with an increasing `x` value at each successive time `t`. The data is taken from snapshots at times in the past, hence they stop at different times.

I've tried my best google-fu, but not really found anything useful, short of manually drawing all the bits of the line.

Here's the code that generates the chart, if it helps:

```
import sys
import json
from datetime import datetime
import itertools
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    colours = itertools.cycle(['r', 'b', 'g', 'm', 'c', 'y', 'k'])

    # A bit of faff for clean printing with globbed arguments:
    filenames = [name.split('.')[0] for name in sys.argv[1:]]

    fig = plt.figure()

    axes = plt.axes()
    axes.set_ylabel('Events')

    for file in filenames:
        data = json.loads(open(file + '.json').read())['results']['data']

        # Unzip to a tuple of lists ([x], [y])
        x, y = zip(*[(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(d['t']/1000)), d['x']) for d in data])
        axes.plot(x, y, colours.next(), label=file)

    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    plt.savefig('plot_{0}.png'.format('_'.join(filenames)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know what exactly is going on without having your data, but in general what you're trying to do should work if you are plotting `Series` which have `datetime` objects as index.

Consider:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10), index=pd.date_range("2016-01-01","2016-10-01",freq="MS"))
b = pd.Series(np.random.rand(5), index=pd.date_range("2016-01-01","2016-5-01",freq="MS"))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a)
ax.plot(b)
```

Output:

[image]

Thus, for your use case consider doing something like

```
axes.plot(pd.Series(y, index=x), colours.next(), label=file)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this. It turns out I'm just a massive idiot and the source of my data was adding an extra point to the end, which is always "now"

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `y` were

```
In [27]: y = np.concatenate([[0,1,4,4,2,3], [4]*3]); y
Out[27]: array([0, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

We'd like to remove the repeated 4's at the tail end of `y` so that it becomes

```
array([0, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4])
```

To do this we could find which values in `y` do not equal the last value in `y`:

```
In [28]: y != y[-1]
Out[28]: array([ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Find the associated ordinal index of the True values:

```
In [29]: np.flatnonzero(y != y[-1])
Out[29]: array([0, 1, 4, 5])
```

and take the last value:

```
In [30]: np.flatnonzero(y != y[-1])[-1]
Out[30]: 5
```

Thus, to crop repeated values off the tail end of `y`, we could use

```
In [31]: y[:np.flatnonzero(y != y[-1])[-1]+2]
Out[31]: array([0, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4])
```

---

Therefore, you could use

```
for file in filenames:
    data = json.loads(open(file + '.json').read())['results']['data']

    # Unzip to a tuple of lists ([x], [y])
    x, y = zip(*[(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(d['t']/1000)), d['x']) for d in data])
    y = np.array(y)
    idx = np.flatnonzero(y != y[-1])[-1]+2
    axes.plot(x[:idx], y[:idx], colours.next(), label=file)
```